# terminate comand executing by subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, streaming, subprocess

I have a python script which listens to specific stream and records it like this:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', 'udp://streamurl:streamport', '-acodec', 'copy', '-f', 'mp3', 'filename.mp3'])
```

Also it checks tcp connection on port 7777 (when stream is live it connects to this port on my pc) I want to terminate subprocess command every time connection on port 7777 closes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
from time import sleep

def connected(sock):
    try:
        sock.send(b'')
    except:
        return False
    return True

handle = Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', 'udp://streamurl:streamport', '-acodec', 'copy', '-f', 'mp3', 'filename.mp3'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

output = ''
while handle.poll() is None and connected(socket): # No exit code given, ergo command still running
    output += handle.stdout.readline()
    sleep(0.025)

if not connected(socket):
    handle.terminate()

output += handle.stdout.read()
handle.stdout.close()
handle.stdin.close()
print(output)
```

**Note**: I have no clue what "socket" is but i'm assuming just a regular socket of sorts.
I'd like to point out that i'm by no means a perfect programmer but this would give you an idea of what you would need to do altho not perfect this would work :)

Comment: If `ffmpeg` generates enough output to fill the pipe buffer or if it reads from stdin then it may block and do *nothing*. Don't set `stdout/stdin` to `PIPE` unless you want to read/write from the pipes. Also `None` is a singleton. Use `something is None` instead of `something == None`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian elaborate on `None` please because you lost me.. What would the actual difference be between using `is` and `==` in this case?

Comment: only `None` is `None`. There could be many objects that are equal to `None` (try it: define `__eq__(other)` method that returns `True` if `other` is `None`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Gotcha! Actually thought Python would interper `is` and `==` the type of the objects the same way.. Guess not :) Thank you for clairifying this!

Comment: pipe handling is widely wrong. `handle.stdout.read()` won't return until *all* output is read. I'm not sure `sock.send(b'')` does anything (it is not relevant to the question. I'd just drop `connected()` definition.

Comment: I meant `send(b'')` might be optimized away *before* hitting real socket (I don't know is it the case).

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call()` is a blocking call - it waits for the subprocess to finish.

You may want to use `subprocess.Popen()` instead, which returns a [Popen object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) that you can interact with and terminate using `Popen.terminate()`.

See the [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).